# Output False of if statement in C

Tags: c, windows, winapi, dll

Can someone please help me with the following problem? I have not included some parts of my code (error handling, etc) in this post to keep it as clear as possible.

When I iterate through the individual items in the buffer and print them out, all the module names are output, where the first one is:

```
C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.WindowsNotepad_11.2309.28.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\Notepad\Notepad.exe
```

However, when I check if the string `Notepad.exe` is included in the corresponding element, the result is false. Sure, for all other modules (DLLs), the result of this `if` statement should be false (after all, `Kernel32.dll` does not contain the string `"Notepad.exe"`), but for this module the output should be true.

Does anyone know why it is not working as expected?

Note `array_modules` has the addresses of the modules.

```
FILE* file_pointer;
HMODULE array_modules[1024];
DWORD number_bytes;
WCHAR BUFFER[1024]; //Unicode characters
int i;
    
BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HMODULE Base_DLL_Address, DWORD Reason_CALL, LPVOID Reserved)
{
    switch (Reason_CALL)
    {
        case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
            fopen_s(&file_pointer, "C:\\Users\\Jonas\\Documents\\test333.txt", "r+");
            int Handle_Process = GetCurrentProcess();             

            char* ImageBase = NULL;
        
            if (EnumProcessModules(Handle_Process, array_modules, sizeof(array_modules), &number_bytes) != 0) {
                for (i = 0; i < (number_bytes / sizeof(HMODULE)); i++) {
                    DWORD Module_LEN_string = GetModuleFileNameEx(Handle_Process, array_modules[i], BUFFER, sizeof(BUFFER));
                    fprintf(file_pointer, "%ls\n", BUFFER);
                    fprintf(file_pointer, "%p\n", array_modules[i]);
                    if (wcsstr(BUFFER, "Notepad.exe") != NULL) {
                        ImageBase = array_modules[i];
                        fprintf(file_pointer, "s\n", ImageBase);
                    }
                    else
                        fprintf(file_pointer, "%s\n", "FAILED");
                }
            }
            fclose(file_pointer);
```

Comment: `wcsstr(BUFFER, L"Notepad.exe")`

Comment: `EnumProcessModules` + `GetModuleFileNameEx` not need and worst choice for get name of **current** process image

Comment: Multiple errors. The type of return value of `GetCurrentProcess` should be `HANDLE`. A value of type `HMOUDLE`(array_modules) cannot be assigned to an entity of type `char`(ImageBase). And the one Retired Ninja said.

Comment: @RbMm What would be a valid alternative? Because I saw some others used GetModuleHandle() but then they retrieve a handle to the module not the actual imagebase?

Comment: @Questions123 I know something. `ImageBaseAddress` is 8 bytes away from the PEB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the wide-character literal that starts with an `L` prefix: `wcsstr(BUFFER, L"Notepad.exe")`.

The type of return value of `GetCurrentProcess` should be `HANDLE` not `int`.

A value of type `HMOUDLE(array_modules)` cannot be assigned to an entity of type `char(ImageBase)`. You need to cast the type.